# Scope for function parameter in C

Tags: c, scope

Is the following code in C correct? I am not 100% sure about the scope of function parameter "a":

```
void method(int a)  
{  
  MyStruct mystruct;
  mystruct.value = (void*) (&a);

  nested_method_call(mystruct);
 }
```

Comment: I think this code is correct, because a will be freed only when execution left method. if nested_method_call will not store argument somewhere in global variable.

Comment: `struct` is a keyword, cannot be used as variable name.

Comment: post your declaration of `struct MyStruct`

Comment: What does your compiler tell you when you turn on all warnings?  (`-wall`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code: `struct.value = (void*)&a;`. Also some other validation needs to be done.

So, if you fully correct your code so that it complies properly then Correct word would be `Lifetime` instead of `Scope`. Lifetime of `a` will be till the end of function `method`. Therefore, `a` can still be accessed inside `nested_method_call` via pointer `struct.value` assuming type of `struct.value` is `int*`.

Comment: is that cast really needed?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Depend upon the type of `struct.value`. If `struct.value` is int then there is no question of lifetime or scope of `a`.

Comment: @sameerkn If `struct.value` is `int` then 1) a cast to `void*` won't be useful, and 2) nothing is different regarding lifetime or scope because we presume that the `int` will be cast back to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `struct` is a keyword in C and cannot be used as a variable name, so this is *wrong* code.

After that, casting an integer to pointer (and vice-versa) is implementation defined behaviour. You should better use `uintptr_t` for better, if you have to get that conversion done.

---

That said, from the basic premises of your question, the logic behind the code seems legit, there's no problem with the scope. In case you meant to ask about the lifetime [*"The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is
guaranteed to be reserved for it"*], then, it is until the end of the `method()` function and you're using it inside that limit, so you're good to go.

Comment: Caution: OP now takes the address of `a` in the last edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume it's:

```
void method(int a)  
{  
  MyStruct x;
  struct.value = (void*) a;

  nested_method_call(x);
 }
```

since `struct` cannot be used as a variable name.
`a`'s scope is the function, so it is alive during `nested_method_call`, however, that is absolutely irrelevant because your `nested_method_call` isn't referring to it -- it's using a *copy* of `a` reinterpreted as `void*`. (Such reintepretation makes the code quite unportable and unusual, by the way. It might be a mistake.)

**Edit:**

```
 void method(int a)  
 {  
      MyStruct mystruct;
      struct.value = (void*) &a;

      nested_method_call(mystruct);
 }
```

is valid (though it's usually a good idea to pass structs by pointer because it's faster for any but very small structs). `&a` is a valid reference until the `}` of `method`.

You also shouldn't need that cast. If `.value` is `void*`, you don't need it. If it isn't, the cast makes `&a` convertible to any other data pointer, which is potentially a dangerous hole in the type system.